# File Upload with Form data in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload files with form data from angular 1.5x to .net core web api controller.
My controller looks like this

```
    [HttpPost]public async Task<ObjectResult> Create(TutorModel model) 
    {
    }
```

My post method is

```html
 return $http.post("/api/Tutor/createTutor/",
      data,
                {
                    withCredentials: false,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    responseType: "arryabuffer"
                });


Where data is


for (var i = 0; i < vm.uploadedFiles.length ; i++) { //vm.upload contains list of file
                data.append(vm.uploadedFiles[i].name, vm.uploadedFiles[i]);
            }
            data.append("tutor", tutor); //tutor is json object
```

Now when it posts to controller, model contains no property value. I get uploaded files in controller if I watch Request.Form.Files.  What is the best method of sending model to post method above. Any pointer? Thanks

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2 - should help

Comment: @Developer I am looking for asp.net core example. thanks for the link though

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net core documentation cover this topic briefly.

Your controller action would be like this.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
   long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

   // full path to file in temp location
   var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

   foreach (var formFile in files)
   {
      if (formFile.Length > 0)
      {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
         {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
         }
      }
    }

     // process uploaded files

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

Where IFormFile have these properties

```
   public interface IFormFile
   {
     string ContentType { get; }
     string ContentDisposition { get; }
     IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
     long Length { get; }
     string Name { get; }
     string FileName { get; }
     Stream OpenReadStream();
     void CopyTo(Stream target);
     Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
   }
```

Note: Use caution when storing binary data in relational databases, as it can adversely impact performance.

Read detail article here
[File Uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Comment: what about viewmodel I want to pass? Cant get my head around it. I have successfully passed files and form data using params but I want to send json object with file. thx

Comment: I created these two models

Comment: `public class Tutor{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class VM{
public VM(){
tutor = new Tutor();
}
public List<IFormFile> files {get;set;}
public Tutor tutor{get;set;}
}

for (var i=0;i<vm.files.length;i++) {
data.append("files",vm.files[i].file);
}
var t={
ID :1,Name:"foo"
};
data.append("tutor.ID", t.ID);
data.append("tutor.Name", t.Name);
$http.post("/api/FileUpload/",data,{
withCredentials:false,
headers:{'Content-Type':undefined },
transformRequest:angular.identity,
responseType:"arryabuffer"
})`

It mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One method to upload the Tutor would be to use JSON.stringify like this:

```
data.append("tutor", JSON.stringify(tutor));
```

Then in your action, parse the JSON string:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] string tutor) 
{
    var tutorObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TutorModel>(tutor);
}
```

You can upload the file in the same request if you convert your js to this:

```
 data.append("files", vm.uploadedFiles[i]);
```

Then add this to your action:

```
[FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using formdata like so

```
const data = new FormData();
```

Then append your files and the json object

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.uploadedFiles.length ; i++) { //vm.upload contains list of file
            data.append(vm.uploadedFiles[i].name, vm.uploadedFiles[i]);
        }
        data.append("tutor", tutor);
```

Then post data.

On the server-side, create a method without any parameters, like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create() {
 // You can access the posted form object from Request.Form
 var vm = Request.Form;
 // your files
 var files = Request.Form.Files;
}
```

Request.Form is key value collection you can get anything you appended using the name.
Name is the first argument in the append method of FormData.